# Photo older than 6 months uploaded in DS-160

Tags: visas, usa, applications, photography

I uploaded a picture older than 6 months during my DS-160 application. 
I used the same picture of a previous Visa application, that had been already cropped with the online tool and so I tought it was good and I used it without reading the requirements (ouch!).
Does someone know if this can cause a Visa denial or if I have a chance to obtain it anyway (like bringing to the interview an updated picture)?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Fattie For what it's worth, the DS-160 is the form for US non-immigrant visas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does someone know if this can cause a Visa denial

I have in the past used pictures as old as seven or more years for visa applications (including USA visas) because I could not be bothered to take new ones.

Once the software accepts your picture, you are pretty much covered. You can carry of a more recent representative picture along if that makes you feel more comfortable however I have never heard a case of someone denied a US visa **because** of a picture.

I have not seen anything in the [Foreign Affairs Manual](https://fam.state.gov/) that says reject/deny a visa application because of a picture.

> Affixing Photograph to Nonimmigrant Visa Applications: The applicant
> will either electronically upload a picture file into Form DS-160 or
> have his/her photo taken at the time when the applicant submits to
> biometric collection at an Applicant Service Center. **In some cases,
> applicants who are unsuccessful in uploading a photo may have to
> submit a physical photo to the consular section**.

**I don’t recommend doing what I did**