# Reuse picture for visa (US & EU)

Tags: visas, usa, europe, photography

US

I got one type of US visa years ago. I applied for a new type of visa recently. I used the same picture again for DS160 and it didn't give me any warning. Can I take the same physical picture to my appointment or should I get a new picture? On the internet I read conflicting information. US website doesn't seem o mention any rules like "don't reuse picture". Picture is old yes but I look the same.

EU

For Schengen visa, do I have to take a new photo for each new visa application or can I reuse them? These visas are given for much shorter amount of time compared to US.

Answer (score 8):

One of the requirements for US Visa photos is that

> The photographs must not be older than six months.

So no, you're not supposed to reuse the photo, assuming it was taken more than 6 months ago.  Whether you'll get away with it is another question, but why risk it?

Source: https://do.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/passports/photo-requirements-u-s-passports-visa/

Comment: Because convenience. Also this guy seem to reuse a 7 year old picture. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126118/photo-older-than-6-months-uploaded-in-ds-160

Comment: @user124360 Your question asked about rules and the answer quotes official information. The question you reference in your comment is 3 years’ old, YMMV.

Comment: Ok gotta bring a new picture just to be safe then in case they ask for a new picture

Comment: I am the person in the answer you linked. I don’t recommend you do the same